# How to add own choice marker in travel direction map?

Tags: google-maps

I was try by set DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true}) but this is not working..

```
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
    #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
</style>

<div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode">
        <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
        <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
        <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
        <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>

    function initMap() {
        var php = <?php echo '{
    "status": "true",
    "msg": "Logs found",
    "logs": [{
            "log_id": "656461",
            "gps_device_id": "1195306005",
            "gps_lat": "19.19706",
            "gps_long": "72.96049",
            "gps_location": "Pipeline Road, Sai Nath Nagar, Jeejamata Nagar",
            "datetime": "2016-05-18 06:34:57"
    },{
            "log_id": "5345435",
            "gps_device_id": "1195306005",
            "gps_lat": "19.53543",
            "gps_long": "72.454354",
            "gps_location": "Pipeline Road, Sai Nath Nagar, Jeejamata Nagar",
            "datetime": "2016-05-18 06:34:57"
    },{
            "log_id": "543543",
            "gps_device_id": "1195306005",
            "gps_lat": "19.43554",
            "gps_long": "72.435435",
            "gps_location": "Pipeline Road, Sai Nath Nagar, Jeejamata Nagar",
            "datetime": "2016-05-18 06:34:57"
    },{
            "log_id": "234234",
            "gps_device_id": "234234234",
            "gps_lat": "22.19707",
            "gps_long": "75.96050",
            "gps_location": "Pipeline Road, Sai Nath Nagar, Jeejamata Nagar",
            "datetime": "2016-05-18 06:34:57"
    }]
}'; ?>
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(php.logs));
//        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        var gps_lat = jsonData[0].gps_lat;
        var gps_long = jsonData[0].gps_long;
        var gps_lat2 = jsonData[jsonData.length - 1].gps_lat;
        var gps_long2 = jsonData[jsonData.length - 1].gps_long;
//        }
        //console.log(gps_lat,gps_long,gps_lat2,gps_long2);
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: {lat: parseFloat(gps_lat), lng: parseFloat(gps_long)}
        });
//        var myLatLng = {lat: parseFloat(gps_lat), lng: parseFloat(gps_long)};
//
//        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
//        position: myLatLng,
//        map: map,
//        title: 'Hello World!'
//      });

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, gps_lat, gps_long, gps_lat2, gps_long2);
//        document.getElementById('mode').addEventListener('change', function() {
//          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay,gps_lat,gps_long,gps_lat2,gps_long2);
//        });



    }

    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, gps_lat, gps_long, gps_lat2, gps_long2) {

        //var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
        directionsService.route({
            origin: {lat: parseFloat(gps_lat), lng: parseFloat(gps_long2)}, // Haight.
            destination: {lat: parseFloat(gps_lat2), lng: parseFloat(gps_long2)}, // Ocean Beach.
            // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
            // using square brackets and a string value as its
            // "property."
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                var leg = response.routes[ 0 ].legs[ 0 ];
                makeMarker(leg.start_location, flag.png, "title");
                makeMarker(leg.end_location, bus_location.png, 'title');
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<!-------------- End ---------------------------->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Please describe it a little more...

Comment: `var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true})` works for me (to suppress the markers), how did you use it that didn't work?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I am trying like var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  suppressMarkers: true
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for change marker icon:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style>
                html, body, #map-canvas {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0px;
                    padding: 0px
                }
            </style>
            <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
            <script>
                var directionsDisplay;
                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                var map;


                function initialize() {
                    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), null);
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                    calcRoute();
                }

                function calcRoute() {
                    var startMarker;
                    var endMarker;
                    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(51.470907, 7.225558);
                    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(52.435293, 10.736883);

                    var startGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    var endGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                    startGeocoder.geocode({'latLng': start}, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[1]) {

                        }
                    });

                    endGeocoder.geocode({'latLng': end}, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[1]) {

                        }
                    });

                    var request = {
                        origin: start,
                        destination: end,
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                    };

                    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                            startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: response.request.origin,
                                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
                                map: map
                            });
                            endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: response.request.destination,
                                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
                                map: map
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```